# Двойное исключение с одинаковой ошибкой

Tags: python, исключения, try

Хочу обработать два одинаковых исключения но исход должен быть разным

```
    try:
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM main_users_db").fetchall()
        for i in cursor:
            await db.add_db(user_id=i[1], group_id=i[0], username=i[2], bio=f'{str(i[4])}', first_name=i[3])
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM user_parse").fetchall()
        for i in cursor:
            await db.add_db(user_id=i[1], group_id=i[0], username=i[2], bio=f'{str(i[3])}', first_name=i[4])
    else:
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM user_parser").fetchall()
        for i in cursor:
            await db.add_db(user_id=i[1], group_id=i[2], username=i[3], bio=f'{str(i[4])}', first_name=i[5])
```

попробовал так не работает

Comment: Попробуйте теперь правильно https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions

Comment: А в зависимости от чего исход должен быть разным? Непонятно.